# extjs 4 grid fireevent itemclick

Tags: extjs4

How do you make a `fireEvent` `itemclick` after the store loads.

I have this but it doesn't work:

```
pcfstore.on('load', function(){
   //auto select first row;
   Ext.getCmp('pcf_grid').getSelectionModel().select(0); // this works

   //fire itemclick event
  var grid= Ext.getCmp('pcf_grid');
  grid.fireEvent('itemclick', grid, 0); //this doesnt work

});
```

Here is my `itemclick` event in grid view:

```
viewConfig: {
    listeners: {
    itemclick: function(dv, record, item, index, e) {
           alert(record.data.code);
       }
    }
}
```

Basically when the grid loads, it should fire the alert window of the selected first row
of the grid.

Answer (score 10):

`itemclick` is event of `View` but not of `Grid`. Try to use:

```
grid.getview().fireEvent('itemclick', grid, 0);
```

And by the way why not use [`selectionchange`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.grid.Panel-event-selectionchange) instead.

**UPDATE**

If you have both `itemcontextmenu` and `selectionchange` handlers it can be a little bit confusing. In this case I recommend back to square one and use `itemclick` event.

But your code need to have some modifications:

1. Assign `itemclick` event to grid, NOT to it's view.
2. When firing `itemclick` pass actual record, NOT an index

like this:

```
grid.getSelectionModel().select(0);
grid.fireEvent('itemclick', grid, grid.getSelectionModel().getLastSelected());
```

And here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/6EezV/) to demonstrate what I'm talking about.

Comment: thanx for the fast response. however -- i've been using this grid Action example which shows context Menu on right-click.  I changed the fireEvent itemclick to Selectionchange as you adviced.  What i wanted to happen is -- if i do left-click of the mouse, it will show the alert message and on right-click shows the context menu.  What it does right now is if i rightclick an item in the Grid, it still shows the alert messagebox. know any workaround that will do the trick? tnx again.

Comment: selectionchange event fires first than itemcontextmenu event -- that's why it still show the alert box even if i do right-click of the mouse.  Thanx again for the help. appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry but I tried this on extjs4.2 and I get the error `Cannot read property 'shiftKey' of undefined` and it points to the `grid.getview().fireEvent('itemclick', grid, 0);` line of code..

Answer (score 0):

After hours of search, I found a solution. It looks like there is an issue with ExtJs4 that make the following functions impossible to work for me:

```
grid.getSelectionModel().select(0);
```

or

```
grid.getView().select(0); // note that this function is deprecated in ExtJS4!!
```

In my controller, I use this code instead:

```
store.load({
    callback: function (records, operation, success) {        
        var rowIndex = this.find('id', myRecord);  //where 'id': the id field of your model. You can replace 'id' with your unique field.. And 'this' is your store.
        grid.getView().select(rowIndex);
    }
})
```

Where myRecord is the record to highlight and select.
It then worked like a charm. I got the row 0 highlighted and selected. However, the itemclick listeners were not fired when the row is select with this code.