# Get Element value in EXTjs GRID

Tags: extjs

how can i get the value of a field of a record in a GRID panel? I have the next code:

```
   var gridTablaConsulta = Ext.create('Ext.grid.GridPanel', {
    title:'Consulta Tabla lotes',
    store: storeTabla,
    columns: [
        Ext.create('Ext.grid.RowNumberer'),
        {text: "NRBE", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'NRBE'},
        {text: "APLIC", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'APLIC'},
        {text: "FORM", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'FORM'},
        {text: "VERFOR", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'VERFOR'},
        {text: "FECLOT", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'FECLOT'},
        {text: "HORLOT", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'HORLOT'},
        {text: "TIPPAPLO", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'TIPPAPLO'},
        {text: "TAMPAP", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'TAMPAP'},
        {text: "FECINIIM", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'FECINIIM'},
        {text: "FECINIOB", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'FECINIOB',editor:{xtype:'textfield', allowBlank:true}},
        {text: "ESTLOT", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex:'ESTLOT',editor:{xtype:'textfield', allowBlank:true}},
        {text: "TOTPAGGE", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'TOTPAGGE'},
        {text: "TOTPAGIM", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'TOTPAGIM'},
        {text: "DESLOT", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'DESLOT'},
        {text: "TIPDIF", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'TIPDIF'},
        {text: "DIADIF", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'DIADIF'},
        {text: "FECALT", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'FECALT'},
        {text: "FECMOD", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'FECMOD'},
        {text: "TERMOD", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'TERMOD'},
        {text: "HORMOD", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'HORMOD'}
    ],
    selType: 'rowmodel',
    plugins: [
        Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
            clicksToEdit: 2
        })
    ],

    listeners: {

         beforeedit: {
             scope: this,
             fn: function(e, context2){
                 var record2= context2.record;
                 var recordData2=record2.getData();
                 alert(JSON.stringify(recordData2));

             }
         },

         edit: function(e, context){
             var record = context.record;
             var recordData = record.getData();
             recordData.Funcionalidad = 'Modificar';
             alert(JSON.stringify(recordData));
             Ext.Ajax.request({
                 url: 'http://localhost:8080/MyMaver/ServletTablaLotes',
                 method: 'POST',

                 // merge row data with other params
                 params: recordData
             });
         }
        }
});
```

I want that when i show the grid and i pulse in a register, i can evaluated the value ot he field "ESTLOT", then i will change that value depends of the previous value.

My problem is that i only know who to obtain all the fieldas that are part of that register, but i only want the ESTLOT value, to pass this value to the edit function where i will evaluated the value.

Thanks for all, i need a lot of help.

EDIT2:

```
 listeners: {

        beforeedit: function(editor, e, eOpts) {
            var grid = Ext.getCmp('gridTabla'); // or e.grid
            var hoy = new Date();

            dia = hoy.getDate(); 

            if(dia<10)
                {
                    dia=String("0"+dia);

                }

            mes = hoy.getMonth();

            if(mes<10)
            {
                    mes=String("0"+mes);

            }
            anio= hoy.getFullYear();
            fecha_actual = String(anio+""+mes+""+dia);
            //alert(fecha_actual);

            var mola = e.record.data.ESTLOT;
            alert(mola);

            if (e.record.data.ESTLOT === '02') {
                if (e.record.data.FECMOD === fecha_actual)
                 {
                e.cancel = false; //permite
                 }
                else{
                    e.cancel = true;
                }

            }  else
            {
                e.cancel = false; //permite
            }

        },

         edit: function(e, context){
             var record = context.record;
             var recordData = record.getData();

             recordData.Funcionalidad = 'Modificar';
             alert(JSON.stringify(recordData));


             Ext.Ajax.request({
                 url: 'http://localhost:8080/MyMaver/ServletTablaLotes',
                 method: 'POST',

                 // merge row data with other params
                 params: recordData
             });
         }
        }
    });
```

Now i would like to pass the var = "mola" include in the beforeedit to the edit to do the last validation

EDIT 3 new code and failure

```
      listeners: {

        beforeedit: 

            function preditar(editor, e, eOpts, mola) {
            var grid = Ext.getCmp('gridTabla'); // or e.grid
            var hoy = new Date();

            dia = hoy.getDate(); 

            if(dia<10)
                {
                    dia=String("0"+dia);

                }

            mes = hoy.getMonth();

            if(mes<10)
            {
                    mes=String("0"+mes);

            }
            anio= hoy.getFullYear();
            fecha_actual = String(anio+""+mes+""+dia);
            //alert(fecha_actual);

            var mola = e.record.data.ESTLOT;
            //alert(mola);
            editar(mola);

            if (e.record.data.ESTLOT === '02') {
                if (e.record.data.FECMOD === fecha_actual)
                 {
                e.cancel = false; //permite
                 }
                else{
                    e.cancel = true; //mo permite
                }

            }  else
            {
                e.cancel = false; //permite
            }

        },

         edit:

             function editar(e, context, mola){

             var record = context.record;
             var recordData = record.getData();
             var mola2= mola;
             alert(mola2);
             recordData.Funcionalidad = 'Modificar';
             //alert(JSON.stringify(recordData));

             Ext.Ajax.request({
                 url: 'http://localhost:8080/MyMaver/ServletTablaLotes',
                 method: 'POST',

                 // merge row data with other params
                 params: recordData
             });
         }
        }
});
```

It said me that "record is null o it is not an object" and apperas here :  var record = context.record;

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sencha: [beforeEdit](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing-event-beforeedit)

**e : Object**
An edit event with the following properties:

**value** - The value for the field being edited.

```
listeners: {
     beforeedit: {
         scope: this,
         fn: function(e, context2){ 
            if(e.value=="ESTLOT"){
              alert("value: " + e.value);
            }
         }
     },
...
}
```

EDIT:

I dont understand very well where you want catch the value, but another case, on controller:

**Catch Event:**

```
'gridView column[action=columnActionName]' : {
    click : me.funcitonInspect
},
```

**Function:**

```
funcitonInspect : function(grid,el,rowIndex){
    var grid = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('grid')[0];
    var selection = grid.getSelectionModel();
    if(selection.hasSelection()){
        var modeloSelected = selection.getLastSelected();
        if(modeloSelected.data.NameField=="ESTLOT"){
               ...
            }
    }
},
```

EDIT2: **Using FireEvent**

maybe you can do a "fireevent" on beforeEdit:

```
this.fireEvent('edit', e, context);
```

[One example:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857242/extjs-4-grid-fireevent-itemclick)

EDIT 3:

try ti get the value with: var record = e.record; the second param is eOpts (The options object) - see the next explanation: [sencha doc](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing-event-beforeedit)

**Example:**

```
edit:

    function editar(e, context, mola){
        var record = e.record;
        ...
    }
},
```

Comment: I want to catch the value before editing that value, because if that value is for example 02 it can not be changed, if that valu is 03 you only can changed to 04.

Comment: i want to catch the value in the beforEdit to pass that value to edit:function

Comment: maybe you can do a "fireevent" on beforeEdit: **this.fireEvent('edit', e, context);** One example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857242/extjs-4-grid-fireevent-itemclick

Comment: how i can use a firevent? can you past who it will be the full code? thanks for all

Comment: could you paste the full code please, now i am a little lost... thanks for all

Comment: ummm i find a failure... i past above my new code and the failure that i found

Comment: record is null o it is not an object" and apperas here : var record = context.record;

Comment: try ti get the value with: **var record = e.record;** the second param is **eOpts** (The options object) - see the next explanation: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing-event-beforeedit

Comment: can you paste a example jejeje... it is dificult to me EXTjs and js, i usually use only java, but now i must use EXTjs and js and really i am a little confused jejeje

Comment: thanks i will try again jejej, appears context is not defined qhe i tried    var mola = e.record.data.ESTLOT;
             editar(e, context, mola);

Comment: i need help in this problem

Comment: I advice you to use the "fireEvent" action, and not call a method on edit event "editar(mola);" .. it's Not Definied because you are calling with one param "mola" and your not sendind a the other params

Comment: ok, but i dont know who to use fireEvet, the api of Extjs is a little extrange for me... but can you post the exact code please...

Comment: Congrats! Put your solution in the question, please! thx a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This is the complete solution. Thanks for all.

```
    listeners: {

        beforeedit: 

            function preditar(editor, e, eOpts) {
            var grid = Ext.getCmp('gridTabla'); // or e.grid
            var hoy = new Date();
            dia = hoy.getDate();  
            if(dia<10)
                {
                    dia=String("0"+dia);

                }
            mes = hoy.getMonth();
            if(mes<10)
            {
                    mes=String("0"+mes);
            }
            anio= hoy.getFullYear();
            fecha_actual = String(anio+""+mes+""+dia);
            e.record.beforeEditESTLOT = e.record.data.ESTLOT;
            if (e.record.data.ESTLOT === '02') {
                if (e.record.data.FECMOD === fecha_actual)
                 {

                    e.cancel = false; //permite probar mañana con cambio fecha
                 }
                else{
                    alert("Solo puedes modificar este estado en lotes modificados en el día actual");
                    e.cancel = true; //no permite
                }

            }  else
            {
                e.cancel = false; //permite
            }

        },

         edit:
             function editar(e, context){
             var record = context.record;
             var recordData = record.getData();
             recordData.Funcionalidad = 'Modificar';
             var modificado = record.modified.ESTLOT; //valores anteriores
             //alert(modificado);
             //var nuevo = recordData.ESTLOT;
             //var cadena = JSON.stringify(recordData);
             //alert(cadena);
             var prueba = context.record.data.ESTLOT;//valores nuevos
             //alert(prueba);
             if ((modificado==='06')||(modificado==='03'))
             {

                 if ((prueba==='01')||(prueba==='02')||(prueba==='03')||(prueba==='06'))
                     {
                     Ext.Ajax.request({
                         //url: 'http://localhost:8080/MyMaver/ServletTablaLotes',
                         url: 'http://lnxntf05:8080/MyMaver/ServletTablaLotes',
                         method: 'POST',
                         // merge row data with other params
                         params: recordData
                     });
                     alert("Modificacion realizada correctamente");
                     }
                 else
                     {

                        alert("Si el valor anterior de estado de lote es 06 o 03 no puede pasar a valer 04 o 05");

                     }   
             }
             if ((modificado==='04')||(modificado==='05'))
             {

                 if ((prueba==='02')||(prueba==='04')||(prueba==='05')||(prueba==='06'))
                     {
                     Ext.Ajax.request({
                         //url: 'http://localhost:8080/MyMaver/ServletTablaLotes',
                         url: 'http://lnxntf05:8080/MyMaver/ServletTablaLotes',
                         method: 'POST',
                         // merge row data with other params
                         params: recordData
                     });
                     alert("Modificacion realizada correctamente");
                     }
                 else
                     {

                        alert("Si el valor anterior de estado de lote es 04 o 05 no puede pasar a valer 01 o 03 o en blanco");

                     }   
             }

             if(modificado==='01')
                 {
                 if ((prueba==='02')||(prueba==='03')||(prueba==='04')||(prueba==='05')||(prueba==='06'))
                 {
                     Ext.Ajax.request({
                     //url: 'http://localhost:8080/MyMaver/ServletTablaLotes',
                     url: 'http://lnxntf05:8080/MyMaver/ServletTablaLotes',
                     method: 'POST',
                     // merge row data with other params
                     params: recordData
                 });
                     alert("Modificacion realizada correctamente");
                 }

                 else
                     {
                     alert("Insertad un valor valido");

                     }

                 }
             if(modificado==='  ')
                 {
                 if ((prueba==='02')||(prueba==='01')||(prueba==='03')||(prueba==='04')||(prueba==='05')||(prueba==='06'))
                 {
                     Ext.Ajax.request({
                     //url: 'http://localhost:8080/MyMaver/ServletTablaLotes',
                     url: 'http://lnxntf05:8080/MyMaver/ServletTablaLotes',
                     method: 'POST',
                     // merge row data with other params
                     params: recordData
                 });
                     alert("Modificacion realizada correctamente");
                 }
                 else
                     {
                     alert("Insertad un valor valido");

                     }

                 }

         }
        }
});
```